# No token in the headers requests (get) with Angular 2

Tags: angular, http-headers, cors, token

I don't understand why the token can't be passed in request. The server (java) doesn't receive the token.

service (angular 2)
...

```
    private authToken: string =  localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  private headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"});
  // private options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers});

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.headers.append("charset", "UTF-8");
    this.headers.append("X-auth_token", this.authToken)
  }

  getCommunes(territoryId: number): Observable<any>{
    return this.http
      .get(`${urlBase}/forms/api/territoires/${territoryId}/communes`, this.headers)
      .map(res => res.json())

  }
```

...
If I use "RequestOptions" it's the same.

Browser console

[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjsMM.png)

Network (nothing in request headers)

[network screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hqEq.png)

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are not using the `RequestOptions` correctly. Try this:

```
private authToken: string =  localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
private headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"});

constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.headers.append("charset", "UTF-8");
    this.headers.append("X-auth-token", this.authToken)
}

getCommunes(territoryId: number): Observable<any> {
   let options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
       headers: this.headers
   });

   return this.http
      .get(`${urlBase}/forms/api/territoires/${territoryId}/communes`, options)
      .map(res => res.json())

}
```

I also think you should use the header name `X-auth-token` (with a dash, and not an underscore)

Comment: What is the `_getInfoRequest` about? @pierreduc

Comment: @FredrikLundin that is something I blindly copied from my own projects. Woops. Thank you for pointing it out :)

Comment: Thank's for your response. I tried it and it is not working. That's maybe a server issue...

Comment: @yabe Yes, it's not a server problem. Are you on the latest version of angular?

Comment: I'm not on v4 but I use one of lastest v2 with cli: 

@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.2
@angular/common: 2.4.10
@angular/compiler: 2.4.10
@angular/core: 2.4.10
@angular/forms: 2.4.10
@angular/http: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10
@angular/router: 3.4.10
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.2
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.10